# Elsa's long term plans on the mountain

Tags: frozen

After Elsa's powers are revealed to the people of Arendelle Elsa runs away and climbs up to the shoulder of an impressive mountain crag. Then she uses her magic to build a majestic ice palace. It is unclear how long all this takes, but I think it is safe to say that Anna doesn't reach the palace until early afternoon.

When Anna does confront Elsa in Elsa's new ice palace Elsa seems to think she will be able to live alone in the ice palace for the rest of her life. However **she would clearly need some support** in the form of food at a minimum. By this time the adrenaline of the flight from Arendelle should have worn off, and Elsa surely would be getting hungry. We know both girls love the smell of chocolate, but that doesn't signal in my mind that Elsa *must* eat.

#### Was Elsa just being obstinate with Anna, or is Elsa capable of living without food/logistical support?

Comment: A very similar question was asked and answered on [SFF:SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66078/how-does-elsa-resolve-the-practical-problems-of-living-in-an-ice-palace)

Comment: @Richard I didn't know about that question. That is a more architecture related question where mine is more of a food related question. You definitely have my up-vote on SFF.SE.

Comment: She eats [ice cream](https://www.facebook.com/DisneyFrozen/posts/851221608228142/), of course.

Comment: @Richard lol and nothing else? Even Cookie Monster is known to partake [in the veggies](http://muppet.wikia.com/wiki/Is_Cookie_Monster_now_the_Veggie_Monster%3F)....

Comment: I'm the first to admit that her plans don't seem well thought through.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Elsa had no long term plan. She spent the latter half of her childhood and all of her teen years as a pariah due to her powers. Her parents died leaving her unequipped to deal with the responsibility of a kingdom. The first time they had opened the gates to the castle in nearly a decade, and snow hits the fan pretty much immediately. Elsa freaks out and climbs a snow covered mountain out of fear. ***The same night, her sister comes to find her.***

This not a well thought out plan. It was a spur of the moment fight or flight response by a teen who thinks she's a monster. The reality of her situation did not hit yet. Logistics wasn't considered.

Then again, it's possible that she's no longer human with a ***need*** for food. Most snow monsters don't eat. She also lacks a need for warmth. Most people would die without a fire or warm clothes for extended time in a freak blizzard. She can also create life by accident.  Olaf and the little snow bastard Snowgies from the short sequel, Frozen Fever. Of course, Elsa catches ***a cold***, so her biology is so strange it's hard to explain.

Historically, Soybeans weren't grown outside of botany curiosities in Norway and Europe until the late 1800s, turn of the century 1900. Ice Cream Sandwiches were first documented in turn of the century 1900 USA. Soy Ice Cream was first created around 1920s USA. [Frozen was set in Norway July of 1839](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Arendelle#Time_period). So soy ice cream sandwich is... ***unlikely***.

Answer (score 6):

### Practical Architecture

The original concept art for Frozen shows a few additional features that were ultimately removed from the film:

**Bedroom**
[image]

**Throne Room**
[image]

### Food

Idina Menzel (the actress who voiced Elsa) stated in a recent [web Q+A](https://www.facebook.com/DisneyFrozen/posts/851221608228142/) that the Queen eats "Soy ice cream sandwiches".

> **Marina Vickery** : *What does Elsa eat in her ice castle? Serious question lol my son wants to know*
>
> **Idina Menzel** : *Elsa eats soy ice cream sandwiches.*

### Drink

It seems reasonable that she could simply melt some snow when she gets thirsty.

---

### (ahem) Pooping

History doesn't record where the Ice Queen [poops](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NobodyPoops) but I suspect that there's an ice toilet somewhere in the palace, complete with an ice bidet. Well, she did say that the cold doesn't bother her...

Comment: I gave you an up-vote based on the *"soy ice cream sandwiches"* bit. The rest of the answer is more architecture than logistics/food though.

Comment: @Erik - I felt that it spoke to her long-term plans and whether the ice palace was actually liveable, at least overnight. The answer is a very firm yes.

Comment: I would agree that the palace is livable, and repairs will be easy given Elsa's magical powers.  What is less clear to me is how Elsa can live alone in the palace without support for an extended period of time. Even if she was a farmer I find it difficult to picture a plot of corn growing in an ice palace...

Comment: The original concept had (evil) Elsa creating an army of "Marshmallows" to invade the kingdom. While the final version of Elsa only created one soldier, there's nothing preventing him (or any other compatriots) from hunting and providing food for the larder.